# What is this in Javascript char = {3:'-', 6:'-'}, tmp=";

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what the following line of code does in Javascript:

```
char = {3:'-',6:'-'}, tmp='';
```

I do not recognize this syntax. It is coming from this block of code:

```
// obj.value = '?V6I0S7I5*5O5S1F2C[]3U4!'; 
function exampleFunction(obj) { 
    var val = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, ''), 
        char = {3:'-',6:'-'}, tmp=''; 
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
        tmp += (char[i]||'') + val[i]; 
    } 
    obj.value=tmp; 
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what this code does and what the value of obj will be.

Comment: its just an object literal for `char` and an empty string for `tmp`.

Comment: `what the value of obj will be` the numeric digits of the input with a hyphen after the 3rd and 6th digit ... so 607-555-1234 - I beleive that's a hollywood phone number in new york state - if you call the number now, you won't believe what happens next

Comment: Thanks... How is it stripping the numbers from that original string? I guess those characters /\D/g are parameters for the replace function? I know /g is to make it find all occurrences globally. But what do the other's do? I thought it was looking for those characters to replace with ' '. Also with that weird code for char, does that mean that the char literal object only has the index 3 and 6? If that is the case wouldn't that generate an error when looping through and the value of i is not an index in char?

Comment: Just google regular expressions tutorial to find out value of `/\D/g`

Answer (score 1):

It is a short hand way of writing variables without having to declare `var` again.

```
function exampleFunction(obj) { 
    var val = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, ''), 
        char = {3:'-',6:'-'}, tmp=''; 
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
        tmp += (char[i]||'') + val[i]; 
    } 
        obj.value=tmp; 
}
```

Is the same as

```
function exampleFunction(obj) {
    var val = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var char = {
        3: '-',
        6: '-'
    }
    var tmp = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
        tmp += (char[i]||'') + val[i]; 
    } 
    obj.value=tmp; 
}
```

**Update**

You are doing some regex replacing in this line of code.

```
var val = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Essentially, you are using the regex meta-character `\D` to find all the occurrences of any non-digit character and replacing them with `''`.

The `char` object could be a dash place holder in a phone number. `ex. 123-123-1234`
The dashes are in **between** locations `3 & 4` and `6 & 7` in the phone number string.

```
var char = {
    3: '-',
    6: '-',
}

var tmp = '';
for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    tmp += (char[i] || '') + val[i];
}
obj.value = tmp;
```

This loop is essentially combining the placeholder `-` with the value at `val[i]`.

`char[i]` will not fail in the loop (well it does), because it is logically OR with an empty string. If a `char[i]` doesn't exist, then it will be an empty string instead.

If you run the code you should see thing as you step through it

```
// obj.value = '?V6I0S7I5*5O5S1F2C[]3U4!'; 
function exampleFunction(obj) { 
    var val = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, ''), // obj.value = 6075551234
        char = {3:'-',6:'-'}, tmp=''; 
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
        tmp += (char[i]||'') + val[i];  
        // Iterations:
        // 0. tmp = "6";
        // 1. tmp = "60";
        // 2. tmp = "607";
        // 3. tmp = "607-5"; <- char[i] exists, so add a '-' + val[i];
        // 4. tmp = "607-55";
        // 5. tmp = "607-555";
        // 6. tmp = "607-555-1"; <- char[i] exists, so add a '-' + val[i];
        // 7. tmp = "607-555-12";
        // 8. tmp = "607-555-123";
        // 9. tmp = "607-555-1234";
    } 
        obj.value=tmp; 
}
```

Basically, you are parsing the given `obj.value` and removing all non-digits and building a phone number from it.

So, `obj.value = ?V6I0S7I5*5O5S1F2C[]3U4!` at the beginning and
`obj.value = 607-555-1234` at the end of this program.

Comment: Thanks for responding....I asked about this more in my comment to the first response....

Answer (score 0):

The line of code in question is declaring 2 local variables and assigning values to them.

The code before the comma is declaring a variable called `char` and assigning to it an object literal with two properties. The code after the comma is declaring a variable called `tmp` and assigning to it an empty string.

You should read this; it will be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals

Comment: Thanks for responding....I asked about this more in my comment to the first response....

Answer (score 0):

Basically the object

```
char = {
   3: '-',
   6: '-'
}
```

is used to take the index and return the value of the property exists, otherwise it returnes an empta string for adding to a string.

```
tmp += char[i] || '';
```

The result is a string with dashes for the index three and six.

Comment: Thanks for responding....I asked about this more in my comment to the first response....